# How to find inconsistent data in the MySQL DB for specified rules?

Tags: mysql, sql

say I have a table such as this (condensed, removed all irrelevant columns):

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(4000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `section_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `questions_section_id_foreign` (`section_id`),

  CONSTRAINT `questions_section_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `sections` (`id`);
```

Now the consistency requirements:

1. All questions within the same section, are supposed to be ordered incrementally starting from 1..N (N being the last question in the section) **using the `order` column**.
2. Question whose `question_type_id` is `6`, need to be grouped together (so if they exist in the section, there must be 3 of them) and they should be ordered 1,2,3 (if question A was the first in the section) , where first one's title = 'A', second = 'B' and third = 'C'. Just to clarify, this type of question is optional, as explained above, if present, 3 expected to be grouped together.

After fixing a bug, **I would like to list all sections, which violate the above consistency requirements, so that they can be fixed manually.**

Example violations can be gap in ordering, multiple questions in a section having the same order number

**Bonus question**: Any constraints we could craft on the DB, to prevent inserting or updating data in a manner that violates the above constraints? I am thinking of it as more of a safeguard in case the application logic slips buggy positions in some unforeseen or untested scenario.

Comment: write a trigger to do the validations.

Comment: @OldProgrammer A trigger for a stored procedure? Ok, and what about the primary question of finding all current consistency violations?

Comment: Maybe you could use Karate to chop at it and report back?

Comment: @easleyfixed I am not sure what is Karate outside of the Martial Art reference, could you be more specific please?

Comment: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/api-testing-with-karate-framework/
API to run your app through to test it for things

Comment: I don't really understand your 2nd requirement. "if they exist in the section": section is not null so everything must exist in a section - not sure why you've said "if...". "there must be 3 of them": why? Where/how is this rule defined or is it just a rule you've defined that is not enforced anywhere? Anyway, if you just want to check that numbering is sequential you can use LEAD() or LAG() window functions

Comment: @NickW I mean, that questions whose type is 6, don't necessarily exist in a section, but if they do, there must be 3 of them, and they must be in specific order as specified above grouped together.

Comment: It is a mistake to try to enforce sequential ordering with no gaps. Databases are _not designed to work this way,_ and so you will end up fighting against the database, instead of letting it work for you. Instead, let the `order` column have gaps. It will be fine. Really. You can then still **easily show the user the 1..N ordering they want at output time**, by using the `row_number()` windowing function.

Comment: But in regard to detecting violations, you can again use a windowing function: `LEAD()` or `LAG()` can show the value from the adjacent row, and then you can filter for rows where the difference is not `1`.

Comment: Finally, could you have more than one question with type 6 in a section, as long as each one is grouped together?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks, you are correct about gaps, but the ordering can be changed by the user, and after a move, the section's ordering gets re-calculated and updated in the DB, keeping it consistent. I just need to fix existing inconsistencies due to previous bugs. Re: Your question about Type 6, to clarify again, IF there is a type 6 question, there MUST be 3 of them in the section, and they MUST be grouped together, sequentially! Anything else is a violation.

Comment: So you couldn't, say, have 6 of them (two separate groups of three)?

Comment: You should not add "bonus question", you need to make two question in two questions and link them. In this case, I'm not looking any try or attempt to resolve this for by yourself, no code to debug. So what is the question?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn No you cant, at least there arent supposed to be - that'd be a bug.. that type of question can only show up once.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli What do you mean link them? Well the second is not as important, just a nice to have.

Comment: @easleyfixed I took a look at what Karate framework does - its for API testing, I am not sure how it is suitable for this task?

Comment: It might not be, but its one tool I see on this site alot that people kick around when they want to test a system they built without having to spend the time actually pretending to be the user and clicking all the buttons to see the actual results.  There might be something better than Karate for this situation probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do queries like the following to use window functions to detect data mistakes. Note that MySQL supports window functions only in version 8.0.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, title, `order`, section_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY section_id ORDER BY `order`) AS out_of_order
  FROM questions
) AS t
WHERE `order` <> out_of_order;

SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, title, `order`, section_id,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY section_id) AS count_not_3
  FROM questions
  where questions.question_type_id = 6
  and questions.deleted_at IS NULL
) AS t
WHERE count_not_3 <> 3 
  and count_not_3 <> 0;

SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, title, `order`, section_id,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY section_id, `order`) AS count_not_1
  FROM questions
) AS t
WHERE count_not_1 <> 1;
```

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oVzjyatV) (edited updated for correct filtering)

These examples might not cover your rules perfectly, but it demonstrates the technique. I'll leave it to you to apply the technique to match your rules fully.

You can't use constraints to prevent these mistakes, because constraints are limited to checking one row at a time.

You would have to write triggers on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE to detect if the change causes a violation of your rules.

Comment: Turns out our DB is currently running on 5.7 :( We cant use these functions currently. I'll try to export the data to local DB running 8, then try to get the list I need. Is there any other way?  Will update if I am successful with 8.

Comment: I'll leave my answer here for the benefit of others. I don't have time to think about how to achieve this with the limitations of MySQL 5.7. That version is near end-of-life.

Comment: Yes please leave it. I'll update on this.

Comment: Update: I have managed to get the data on version 8, that solution works with a minor tweak: the first query needed to be ordered by the 'order' and not the ID, to count correctly.
https://dbfiddle.uk/UEnpNWCA Shows the updated first query (will edit your response to reflect this).

However the second query for the question type 6, was not done correctly which is my fault not properly defining the conditions. I have updated it in the fiddle as well, but its not working correctly. There can either be 0 questions of type 6 in a section, or 3. Anything else is anomaly. so I tried to add == 6

Comment: And its not working, @BillKarwin. How do I get the syntax right, so the second query only counts the questions in a section, that their type ==6?

Comment: I encourage you to read the [documentation on window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html).

Comment: Thank you @BillKarwin, I've updated the answer to filter correctly, it is now good enough!